# Natural Join is not returning blank rows

Tags: mysql, natural-join

I have following table and their columns:

> 1. ACTOR containing actor_id(primary key), first_name, last_name, last_update as columns
> 2. FILM_ACTOR containing actor_id(primary Key), film_id(primary key), last update as columns

Actor_id in both tables have same datatype and Equal values.

I have written the following MySQL Query in SQL workbench:

```
select actor_id, first_name, film_id from actor natural join film_actor;
```

But its returning zero or blank rows. Why?

Comment: Try to do left join, see if that helps

Comment: But why Natural Join is not returning any results. What if I want to use only Natural Join

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the NATURAL JOIN is such a join that performs the same task as an INNER or LEFT JOIN, in which the ON or USING clause refers to all columns that the tables to be joined have in common.

So in your case, it will try to join on actor_id as well as last_update columns which you may not want. I would suggest you use INNER JOIN like below:

```
SELECT actor_id, first_name, film_id 
FROM actor a INNER JOIN film_actor f 
ON a.actor_id = f.actor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join with reference for join column.

`select actor_id, first_name, film_id from actor inner join film_actor using (actor_id)`